# Python, Webiopi and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, robotics, webiopi

I am trying to control my Raspberry Pi car via wireless and webiopi.  The basic function works fine - have the interface where I click fwd and the car will go forward and when I release the button it will stop.

I now want to integrate the Ultrasonic distance sensor so that when I drive forward, the car should stop when something is in front of it.  I have it going where when I click to fwd button, the car will drive and stop when something is in range but it will only stop when something is in range and not when I release the button. My while loop is somehow looping (stuck) and not reading the release button function from webiopi.

Can somebody please help - been at it for days now and not sure where I am going wrong :-(

Here is the loop from my python script:

```
def go_forward(arg):
  global motor_stop, motor_forward, motor_backward, get_range
  print "Testing"
  print mousefwd()
  while (arg) == "fwd":
      print (arg)
      direction = (arg)
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % get_range()
      if direction == "fwd" and get_range() < 30:
          motor_stop()
          return
      else:
          motor_forward()
```

And here is the code from my webiopi function call:

```
 function go_forward() {
              var args = "fwd"
              webiopi().callMacro("go_forward", args);
      }
 function stop1() {
              var args = "stop"
              webiopi().callMacro("go_forward", args);
              webiopi().callMacro("stop");
    }
```

This is how I have it now but still not working (I am a total noob :-) ) :

```
 def go_forward(arg):
  global motor_stop, motor_forward, motor_backward, get_range
  print "Testing"
  direction = arg
  while direction == "fwd":
      print arg
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % get_range()
      if get_range() < 30:
         motor_stop()
      elif direction == "fwd":
         motor_forward()
      else:
         motor_stop()
```

Maybe a slight step forward.  See that webipi uses its own 'loop' and I added the loop code to check what the status of the motor GPIO's are and the distance and if the motor is running and if the distance is too short then stop. Car moves now when I press the forward button and stops when I release it and when moving forward and distance is less then 30cm it will stop.  Only problem is that when the distance is too short and I press the forward button too quickly multiple times, I now get a "GPIO.output(Echo,1)
_webiopi.GPIO.InvalidDirectionException: The GPIO channel is not an OUTPUT"  error :-(  .

The Code looks now like this:

```
 def go_forward(direction):
   motor_forward()

 def loop():
   if get_range() < 30 and GPIO.digitalRead(M1) == GPIO.HIGH:
     stop()
     print "stop"
   sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your main problem in a minute, but first I want to mention something you're doing as a Python beginner, which is making your life more complicated than it needs to be.

There's no need for the `global` statement you have at the start of your function. In Python, you only need to use the `global` statement if you want to *write* to a global variable. If all you need to do is *read* the variable, or call the function, then there's no need for the `global` statement. Any names used in your function, whether they're names of variables or names of functions, will be searched for in the following order: local, enclosing, global, builtin. "Local" means names defined inside your function, like your `direction` variable. "Enclosing" is a rule used when you define a function inside another function. This is useful in many situations, but is a bit of an advanced topic and you don't need to worry about it for now. "Global" means names (of variables, or functions, or classes) defined at the top level of your program -- such as your `motor_stop` function among others. And finally, "builtin" means Python's built-in names, like `str` or `int` or `file`.

So if you left out the `global` statement, then Python would search for the name `motor_stop` (and the other function names) as follows:

1. **Local:** Is there a `motor_stop` defined in this function? No. Moving on.
2. **Enclosing:** Is this function defined inside another function? No, so the "enclosing" rule doesn't apply. Moving on.
3. **Global:** Is there a `motor_stop` defined at the top level of the program? Yes. Found it.
4. (Builtin): This rule is never checked at all, because the name was found by the "global" rule.

All of your functions are defined at the top level of your program, so the "global" rule will find them with no need for the `global` statement. This should make your life a little simpler.

Now for your main question: why your code is looping forever. That's because the test condition your `while` loop will never become false. You are looping on `while direction == "fwd"`, and the code inside the `while` loop never changes the `direction` variable. So every time it reaches the end of the loop, it goes back to test the condition again. The `direction` variable still contains the string `"fwd"`, and so the while loop runs a second time. Then the `direction` variable still contains the string `"fwd"`, and so it runs a third time. And so on, and so on.

One way to exit the `while` loop when you want it to exit would be to set the `direction` variable to something else, like `"stop"`, when you want to stop. (E.g., after you call `motor_stop()`). Another way would be to use the `return` statement to exit the function at that point. But my suggestion would be to use the `break` statement instead, which means "At this point, immediately exit the loop I'm in." It works on both `while` loops and `for` loops, and is a very useful statement to know about. It looks like you want your `while` loop to exit any time you call `motor_stop()`, so there are two places you'd put a `break` statement:

```
def go_forward(arg):
  print "Testing"
  direction = arg
  while direction == "fwd":
      print arg
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % get_range()
      if get_range() < 30:
         motor_stop()
         break
      elif direction == "fwd":
         motor_forward()
         # No break statement here, so the while loop continues
      else:
         motor_stop()
         break
```

There are a few other changes I'd suggest making. First, you call `get_range()` three times in your loop, but you really only need to call it once. You've already assigned its result to a `dist` variable, so why not use that variable?

```
def go_forward(arg):
  print "Testing"
  direction = arg
  while direction == "fwd":
      print arg
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % dist
      if dist < 30:
         motor_stop()
         break
      elif direction == "fwd":
         motor_forward()
         # No break statement here, so the while loop continues
      else:
         motor_stop()
         break
```

And second, there's no way inside the `while` loop for `direction` **not** to be "fwd", so the final `else` is unnecessary, and your function can become:

```
def go_forward(arg):
  print "Testing"
  direction = arg
  while direction == "fwd":
      print arg
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % dist
      if dist < 30:
         motor_stop()
         break
      else:
         motor_forward()
```

Finally, you have a function parameter named `arg`, which is a name that tells you nothing about what it's used for. You immediately assign it to a variable called `direction`, which is a much better name. So why not use that as the parameter name in the first place? There's no rule that says a function's parameters *must* be called "arg"; they can be called anything you like (except one of Python's reserved words like `break` or `if`). So let's give your function a more meaningful parameter name, and that will simplify it even further:

```
def go_forward(direction):
  print "Testing"
  while direction == "fwd":
      print direction
      dist = get_range()
      print "Distance %.1f " % dist
      if dist < 30:
         motor_stop()
         break
      else:
         motor_forward()
```

There. That's much easier to read and understand, and it should solve the problem you were seeing of your `while` loop not exiting when the car gets too close to an object.

(There's still one possible problem I can see, which is that the while loop might not exit while the car is driving forward, even though you released the "forward" button -- but I'd have to see your `motor_forward()` code to know how to solve that one. It might be as simple as putting a `break` statement after `motor_forward()`, in which case there would really be no need for a `while` loop at all -- but I'd have to know how your `motor_forward()` code interacts with webiopi and how webiopi's event-handling code works. None of which I know right now, so I'm going to answer what problems I can answer now even if my answer is incomplete, rather than leave you with no answer at all.)

**Edit by Mark:** Here is the motor_forward code:

```
 def motor_forward():
     GPIO.output(M1, GPIO.HIGH)
     GPIO.output(M2, GPIO.LOW)
     string = "echo 0=130 > /dev/servoblaster"
     os.system(string)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and effort for explaining and pointing out in detail to where my problem might be !  Also, thank you for explaining the python code in so much detail!  I really appreciate this. I will test the script tonight as for I am now off to work - but can't wait to try it out. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark - You're welcome. By the way, be aware that I made an editing mistake at one point when I was copying and pasting your code and editing it, and a couple of lines ended up as `else direction == "fwd":`. Those lines **should** have been just `else:`. I've edited my answer to fix those mistakes, but if you've already copied & pasted from my answer before seeing this comment, you'll want to grab the newly-edited, corrected version.

Comment: ok, the code looks much better now and seems to run way more smoothly but still having the problem where the while loop does not register that I release the forward button.  I will continue to play with the code.  Here is the motor_forward() code:                        `def motor_forward():
    GPIO.output(M1, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(M2, GPIO.LOW)
    string = "echo 0=130 > /dev/servoblaster"
    os.system(string)`

Comment: I just again want to thank you for teaching me so much in regards to python and how def and loops work.  I am going to mark your answer as correct although I still need to figure out how I will get my raspberry car to work without my new error - might have to ditch webiopi and try some different way of controlling my car via a web interface but I will still but some more time into it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mark - I see you've made a major re-write of your code. If you're having problems with the re-written version, I'd be glad to help with those as well, but editing this question might not be the best way to do it since I can only give one answer per question, and making major edits to an already-accepted answer is not a good idea. If you need help with your new code, open a new question for it and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Thank you,  I will definitely take you up on the offer. You have been of great help to me and you explained the python way so well that I was able to get out of my own loop in my head :-) I will later paste my new code and maybe the whole code into a new question just so that you can maybe have a look and maybe give an idea of going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - you always stop on range but may want to stop on direction

```
  if get_range() < 30:
      motor_stop()
  elif direction == "fwd":
      motor_forward()
  else:
      motor_stop()
```

btw you dont need the (arg) only arg when you reference it

print arg

the parens in the call signature are there to show its a parm to a function

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.  I am very new to python but I can see what your code is doing and it makes 100% sense.  Unfortunately it still does not want to work :-(  somewhere it still get stuck in a loop.

Comment: <code>def go_forward(arg):
      global motor_stop, motor_forward, motor_backward, get_range
      print "Testing"
      direction = arg
      while direction == "fwd":
          print arg
          dist = get_range()
          print "Distance %.1f " % get_range()
          if get_range() < 30:
             motor_stop()
          elif direction == "fwd":
             motor_forward()
          else:
             motor_stop() </code>